# Why is using multiple threads not improving performance?

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient

So I've been trying stuff with the c# `WebClient`. I managed to make a working program (console application) with code similar to this:

```
static void Search(string number)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < globalvariable.lenght; a++)
        {
            string toWrite = "nothing";
            for (int b = 0; a < globalvariable2.lenght; b++)
            {
                string result = client.DownloadString(urlString);
                //do stuff with toWrite if page is not empty
                //change toWrite and break the b loop
            }
            Console.WriteLine(toWrite);
        }
    }
}
```

It isn't really fast so I thought I can make it faster by using multiple threads.
It takes 2 minutes to execute.

So I tried making the loop a `Parallel.For` loop. It still took 2 minutes to execute. So I read stuff in here and made the following code:

```
static async Task AWrite(string number, int a) 
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        string toWrite = "nothing";
        for(int b=0; a<globalvariable2.lenght; b++)
        {
            string result = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
            //do stuff with toWrite if page is not empty
            //change toWrite and break the b loop
        }
        Console.WriteLine(toWrite);
    }
}
```

And then the function to call it:

```
private static void ASearch(string number)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for(int a=0; a<gobalvariable.Length; a++)
    {
        tasks.Add(AWrite(number, a));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

So I thought that multiple `WebClient` will download the strings simultaneously, apparently that doesn't happen as this also takes two minutes to execute. Why is that? By the writing in the console I know that they are not executing in order, but it still takes same amount of time. How can I actually improve performance of the first function through the use multiple threads?

Comment: i think a web client can only handle only 1 request at a time.

Comment: A single one I am sure can handle only one. But since I am basically using multiple clients on different threads, can those multiple clients not make more than one request?

Comment: a task may map to different threads, or it may not.

Comment: so you are saying that it may be possible that **every** webclient request is executing on the same thread? If so is there any way I can change that? EDIT: Every time, all of them (usually 23)?

Comment: @nix The work that you're doing is not CPU bound work, it's IO bound work.  *No threads* are being used while that IO is happening.  A thread is only needed to send the initial request (and you only ever use one thread for that) and to process the responses after you get them (which you technically allow to happen on multiple threads if there is no synchronization context, but that's a miniscule portion of the work you're doing).  The ability of your network connection to handle concurrent requests is unrelated to what threads are running on the CPU and what they're doing.

Comment: So I've just done some additional info gathering. Every time DownloadStringTaskAsync takes about 2-3 seconds. The thing is it takes 2-3 second when the string is 495 characters long and the same amount when the string is 378k characters long. Since my internet connection is ~40Mbps I don't think that's the limiting factor? EDIT: I don't think writing to the HDD 495 chars is limiting it either.

Comment: @nix For payloads that small the time is dominated by the latency of sending *any* data, and is also affected by whatever processing time is required by the other server.  A slightly bigger or smaller file size in the request/response isn't going to matter much until you get *really* big files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the limitation is in the site I am downloading from. It limits to 1 HTTP connection per person. Thanks for the thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the HTTP connection limit:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 5;
```

Check out [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) and also the article on the [ServicePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.aspx) class. With this property you can change the default connection limit for HTTP connections.